# Retrieve HTTP error details in /error controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am using `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"` and want to report error details via email notifications to Admins. I don't know how / where to **capture detailed error information when an HTTP error is thrown** and the View is called - especially need HTTP 500s.

I would like to insert the current error details in the Controller where marked <-- ADD DETAILS HERE. Disclaimer: I am aware of the performance issues with error emailing and background `Thread` and will optimize 'later'). I am using MVC 5.2.3.0.

My `web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/error/error">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/error/badrequest" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/error/forbidden" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/notfound" />
    <error statusCode="414" redirect="/error/urltoolong" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error/internalserver" />
    <error statusCode="503" redirect="/error/serviceunavailable" />
</customErrors>
```

My `errorInfo` viewmodel:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class ErrorInfo
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `ErrorController` (only showing HTTP 500):

```
public ActionResult InternalServer()
{
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.Code = "500 - Internal Server Error";  <-- *ADD DETAILS HERE*
    SendHttpErrorAsync(errorInfo.Code);
    return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
}

public void SendHttpErrorAsync(string message)
{
    Thread httpError = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            message = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? message + " | " + User.Identity.GetUserName() : message + " | anonymous";
            message = message + " | " + Request.UserHostAddress; /*(::1 is localhost)*/
            try
            {
                var requestUri = string.Format("http://ip-api.com/xml/{0}", Request.UserHostAddress);
                var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                message = (xdoc.Element("query").Element("status").Value == "success") ? message + " | " + xdoc.Element("query").Element("city").Value : message + " | location unvailable";
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            MyProject.Helper.Email.sendErrorEmail(message);
        });
        httpError.IsBackground = true;
        httpError.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is the use Elmah for Asp.net - all functionalities are already built in.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc, you can catch application level errors on Application_Error event on Global.ascx file. Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzzh56s.aspx). We can define 
Just add the following method to the global ascx file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    MyProject.Helper.Email.sendErrorEmail((ex.InnerException != null) 
                  ? ex.InnerException.Message
                  : "");

}
```

Usually I prefer logging the exceptions to a database, on top of that you can set up a Notification service.